# Interrupt doesnt work in while loop. STM32

Tags: stm32, interrupt

I am trying to write a code which does different things depending on if the button is long or short pressed. My problem is that in the last while loop at the very bottom (where the light is supposed turn on and off periodically), interrupts dont seem to work. I press the button and nothing happens, it keeps toggling on-off. I checked this by putting breakpoints in the debugger. Even when the button is pressed, it doesnt leave the loop. Why is the interrupt not working in that while loop? What should i do to make it work?

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdbool.h>
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint32_t currentmillis = 0;
uint32_t previousmillis = 0;
uint32_t odd = 2;
static bool var = true;
uint32_t counterinside = 0; //testing
uint32_t counteroutside = 0; //testing
uint32_t timer;
static bool longpress = false;


/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      timer = 10000000;

      while(timer > 0 && (odd % 2 == 1)) {
          timer--;
      }

      if( (timer == 0)){
          longpress = true;
      }

      if(longpress == true){
          while(1){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              timer = 10000000;
                  while(timer > 0) {
                      timer--;
               }
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              timer = 10000000;
                  while(timer > 0) {
                      timer--;
                          }
          }
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1_BOOST);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 85;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
      counteroutside++; //testing
      currentmillis = HAL_GetTick();
      if((GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_9) && (currentmillis - previousmillis > 10))
      {
          counterinside++; //testing

          if (odd % 2 == 0){
              odd = odd + 1;
              previousmillis = currentmillis;
              longpress = false;
          }

          else if (odd % 2 == 1 && longpress != true)
          {

              if(var == true)
              {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              var = false;
              }
              else
              {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              var = true;
              }

              longpress = false;
              previousmillis = currentmillis;
              odd = odd + 1;
          }

          else if (longpress == true){
            odd = odd + 1;
            while(1){
                          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                          timer = 10000000;
                              while(timer > 0) {
                                  timer--;
                           }
                          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                          timer = 10000000;
                              while(timer > 0) {
                                  timer--;
                                      }
                      }
          }

      }


    }

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

For more detail, i made the button falling/rising mode. And interrupt does work in the first while loop where the light repedately toggles. When button is released (falling edge) interrupt works as it should and code reaches the second while loop where light repedately toggles. But in this loop interrupt doesnt work, aka button doesnt work.

I wrote code in while loop in main and in "USER CODE BEGIN 4".

Comment: You appear to have an infinite `while(1)` loop in `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback function that contains the loop where interrupts don't work is called by the interrupt handler. Technically, the callback function is a part of the interrupt handler - simply the last line of the interrupt handler. You are already inside EXTI interrupt handler, and you want EXTI interrupt to happen, therefore EXTI interrupt will not occur. It can't exit current interrupt handler to enter the interrupt handler again.

Solution: reorganize the entire logic of the program so that there are no infinite loops inside interrupt handlers (including callbacks). They're supposed to run and return asap. The first option that comes to mind would be to find a way to have all loops inside your main() while(1) loop, which can be preempted by interrupt handlers and their callbacks.