# STM32 Program ignores condition and enters into the function

Tags: conditional-statements, stm32

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdbool.h>
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint32_t currentmillis = 0;
uint32_t previousmillis = 0;
uint32_t odd = 2;
static bool var = true;
uint32_t counterinside = 0; //testing
uint32_t counteroutside = 0; //testing
uint32_t timer;
static bool longpress = false;


/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      if(longpress == true){
          while(1){
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                        timer = 10000000;
                                 while(timer > 0) {
                                     timer--;
                                 }
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                        timer = 10000000;
                                  while(timer > 0) {
                                  timer--;
                                  }
                 }
      }

      timer = 10000000;

      while(timer > 0 && (odd % 2 == 1)) {
          timer--;
      }

      if( (timer == 0)){
          longpress = true;
      }

      if(longpress == true){
          while(1){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              timer = 10000000;
                  while(timer > 0) {
                      timer--;
               }
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              timer = 10000000;
                  while(timer > 0) {
                      timer--;
                          }
          }
      }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1_BOOST);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 85;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
      counteroutside++; //testing
      currentmillis = HAL_GetTick();
      if((GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_9) && (currentmillis - previousmillis > 10))
      {
          counterinside++; //testing

          if (odd % 2 == 0){
              odd = odd + 1;
              previousmillis = currentmillis;
              longpress = false;
          }

          else if (odd % 2 == 1 && longpress != true)
          {

              if(var == true)
              {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              var = false;
              }
              else
              {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              var = true;
              }

              longpress = false;
              previousmillis = currentmillis;
              odd = odd + 1;
          }

          else if (longpress == true){
            odd = odd + 1;
            }

      }


    }

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMyzd.png)

As seen in the image, program enters into the "if" function in c:137 despite "longpress" variable being false as it can be seen in debug menu on the right. How come it ignores the if condition "longpress == true"?

Also i put breaking points to c:129 and c:133 as well but after the program returns from a callback, it jumps straight into the "if" function at c:137, doesnt pause like it should at 129 or 133 while debugging.

If i press the button it leaves the if function only to return to it immediately. I dont get it.

Comment: Possibly because `longpress` is being set to false in your ISR, as seen in your recent [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922188/interrupt-doesnt-work-in-while-loop-stm32).

Comment: Most likely, you first enter the loop, after that ISR turns `longpress` false, but once the ISR exits, the MCU returns exactly where it was - back inside that loop. And there is no way to exit it from the inside, if `longpress` turns false.

Comment: Also, please post the code as text, and embed images (but not of code, code only as text). You expect others to help you, so please spend extra 30 seconds to make it comfortable for the others (and such are the question guidelines). It does actually affect response rate, if you need extra motivation for it. Thank you.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Can you help me understand? If longpress is set to false in ISR, is it still true outside the ISR? Is that why the problem is happening? How can i make the longpress = false apply everywhere in the code even if its written in ISR?

Comment: @TheBlitz first of all, if you have a variable that you change inside interrupt, it must be volatile. Otherwise, for optimization reasons, you can get undefined behavior. Second of all, even if `longpress` changes the value in ISR, you're already inside while(1), which is inside `longpress==true` loop. So yes, `longpress` changed, but once inside the loop, there is no more check if `longpress` changed value. You already entered the loop, and while inside it, `longpress` can become anything, it will never be checked again.

Comment: @Ilya oh i see, i thought whenever a callback happens, program returns to the first while(1). It just returns to where it was left off. makes sense. its been a while i worked on C thank you ;D

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some misunderstanding of how if() and while() work, so let's walk through your program and see why it's stuck inside the loop.

Initially, `if(longpress == true)` is tested, if it's true, you enter this if. Immediately you enter `while(1)` inside it. So whatever is inside `while(1)`, it's executed again and again and again forever.

So let's imagine `longpress` was true at some point, you entered the `if`. You were inside that `while(1)` loop going over and over a thousand times, and then `longpress` suddenly becomes false. What happens then? Well, your code just executes the next line in that loop. And then the next line. And then the next line. And then after the last line of the loop, it checks the `while(1)` condition, which is always true. So the loop starts all over again. In other words, your code inside the loop never checks if `longpress` became false. You just tested the value of `longpress` once when you entered the loop, but it's never tested ever again. The line `if(longpress==true)` was executed only once - at the start, and never again. After that even if the `longpress` becomes false, you will still stay inside that loop, because you already are inside, and nothing inside the loop tests if longpress changed its value. The conditions in outer loops or functions don't matter at all, because to matter, they have to be executed again. But you're stuck within the inner loop.

```
if(longpress == true){
    while(1){
        /* You're stuck inside this loop. Loop start. */
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        timer = 10000000;
        while(timer > 0) {
            timer--;
        }
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        timer = 10000000;
        while(timer > 0) {
            timer--;
        }
        //Loop end. Check if while() condition is true. 
        //1 is always true. Return back to loop start. longpress is never tested
    }
}
```

The solution would be to replace the double condition

```
if(longpress == true){
    while(1){
```

with a single condition

```
while(longpress==true) {
```

which means every time the loop round is finished, this condition is tested again. And if it's false, the loop doesn't start again and it simply exits. Now you have a condition test every time the loop happens.

Alternatively, you can have

```
if(longpress == true){
    while(1){
        if(longpress==false) break;
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Which would be identical logic. The point is to explicitly test `longpress` every loop round. It's better to use the first method, as logic-wise they're identical, but the code of the first solution is simpler.